# is it possible to change the whole name of diaspora to something else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-networking, diaspora

I had installed diaspora working in development mode.I wanna ask can I change the app name from everywhere (am not asking about changing the pod name) or can i just hide or escape some of its functions like **Invite your friends**  and **Bookmarklet**  panel. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716532/how-to-change-my-pod-name-in-diaspora#comment45790643_28716532 as your question gets answered there.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the app name everywhere" if you don't mean the pod name?